# "Comma Code" Program from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python through the book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" by Al Sweigart. I am finishing up a chapter on lists, and I have a program prompt called "Comma Code":

> Say you have a list value like this:
>
> ```
> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with *and* insrted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return `'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'`. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it. "

Here is my code so far:

```
def commaCode(newList):
   print(str(newList[:-1]) + 'and' + ' ' +  str(newList[-1]))
   return

nextlist = []
anotherlist = input('Enter a value')
while anotherlist != '':
   nextlist = nextlist + list(anotherlist)

commaCode(nextlist)
```

I feel this should work, but whenever I type in an input of some sort, the program simply allows me to put in more input, and nothing happens. I then try to exit out of the program and it asks if it wants me to "kill the program". I am not sure what the problem with my code is... I assume it may be with the "while" statement, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderfully frustrating world of programming. When you encounter problems like this, it is important to be able to track them down. We call this "debugging" which is one of the most important skills to develop. For a start, check out the tips at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some ideas of how to track down the problems in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Good effort. Your function is reasonably close, but your `while` will run infinitely because `anotherList` never changes inside the loop block. `nextlist` will keep expanding in this loop, though, with whatever string the user passed into `input()` broken into characters. Eventually, the program will run out of memory and crash.

Don't take my word for it: `print` the variable that is supposed to terminate the loop inside the loop block and see what it's doing on each pass (important debugging skill).

There's a few ways to fix this. The below approach allows the user to enter input on each loop pass, the result of which either `break`s the loop if empty or is appended to the accumulating list of user input if not.

```py
def comma_code(items):
    if not items:
        return ""
    elif len(items) == 1:
        return items[0]
    return ", ".join(items[:-1]) + f" and {items[-1]}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = []

    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter a value: ")

        if user_input == "":
            break

        items.append(user_input)

    print(comma_code(items))
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a value: 1
Enter a value: 2
Enter a value: 3
Enter a value: 3
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 5
Enter a value:
1, 2, 3, 3, 4 and 5
```

Note that the variable names are `snake_cased` rather than `camelCased` per the [Python coding standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

I also removed the `print` that was in your `commaCode` function. This is a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) and is generally undesirable because the function isn't multi-purpose: it only prints stuff to stdout and can't offer much else. If you return the result, the caller can choose what to do with it (print it, reverse it, put it in a database...).

Also note that if the user inputs nothing or one item, the original code would either crash or produce a poorly formatted output, respectively. I've handled these cases in the above code.

Comment: Adding and should be conditional on having at least two elements.

Comment: Also, the problem calls for an Oxford comma

Answer (score 1):

The second way was to actually use a function on pre-defined lists in the program.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

otherlist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

def niceSentence(list):

    for item in list[:-1]:
        print(item + ", ", end='')

    print("and " + list[-1])

niceSentence(spam)

niceSentence(otherlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer. If the list is empty it should print "Nothing to see here". A list with one item should print just that item, and a list with a length greater than one should produce the desired result. Hopefully this is correct, would appreciate any feedback.

```
spam = ['pizza','tofu','boats','hoes']




   def comma_code(values):
        if len(values) < 1:
            print('Nothing to see here.')
        elif len(values) == 1:
            print(values[0])
        else:
            print(', '.join(values[:-1]) + ' and ' + values[-1])

    comma_code(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did mine in two ways, each of which incorporates steps that you used. Both work, but get their list input from different sources. One asks for user input, the same as you did. However, it does not actually define a function; rather, the program is the function. (I modeled this approach off the program "allMyCats2.py" in the middle of Chapter 4.)

```
anyList = []
while True:
    print('Enter an item for your list, or hit enter to stop.')
    item = input()
    if item == '':
          break
    anyList = anyList + [item]

for item in anyList[:-1]:
    print(item + ",", end='')

print("and " + anyList[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This combines the two approaches:

```
def niceSentence(list):
    for item in list[:-1]:
        print(item + ", ", end='')
    print("and " + list[-1])        #this defines the function that makes the comma list


anyList = []

while True:
    print('Enter an item for your list, or hit enter to stop.')
    item = input()
    if item == '':
          break
    anyList = anyList + [item]      #builds list from inputted strings

niceSentence(anyList)  #calls function on built list
```

Comment: In the future, you can edit your original question. You should probably do that and delete the two extra ones.

Answer (score 0):

i did this short one

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def list_funk(theliste):
    for mot in theliste[:-1]: # first i work with index 0 to 3
        print(mot, end=', ')
    print('and ' + str(spam[-1])) # then adding what misses to complete exercise

list_funk(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basic approach to the question of comma code practice project.
The answer is written using the knowledge obtained from the book till the chapter LISTS. No additional or advanced concepts included.

### Answer Code

```
userInput=[]
#Enter the number of total entries in the list
n =int(input("Enter the number of input elements: "))
for i in range(0,n):
    newInput=input() #This gets the list values
    userInput.append(newInput)

#Function to execute the program
def commaList(userInput):
    for i in range(len(userInput)):
        if i == len(userInput)-1:
            print(' and '+userInput[i])
        else:
            print(userInput[i], end=',')
    return
commaList(userInput)
```

Example

```
#Console Screen:
Enter the number of input elements: 4
Maths
Science
History
Music
#ProgramOutput:
Maths,Science,History, and Music
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I first declared a spam list, then defined the commaCode function.  I then added an 'and' to the last item of the list, then used a for loop to add a comma to every item before the last one in the list.  In case the items were not string datatypes, I converted them.

because we wanted to print out long string with all the items, i declared an empty string variable stringList, and used a for loop to append all the items to stringList.

Lastly, I printed out the stringList.

---

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats', 8, True]  #our list

def commaCode(myList):

    myList[-1] = 'and ' + str(myList[-1])  #converted last element to string and 
                                           #added an 'and'
    for i in range(len(myList)-1):    #add a comma to every element before
        myList[i] = str(myList[i]) + ', '

    stringList = ''                 #declare an empty string variable
    for i in range(len(myList)):    #add each element to the string list
        stringList = stringList + str(myList[i]) 

    print(stringList)               #print the entire string list

commaCode(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_value(s):
    while " " in s:
        s.remove(" ")
    while "" in s:
        s.remove("")
    return str(", ".join(s[:-1])) + " and " + str(s[-1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spam = ["apples", "bananas", "tofu", "cats"]

    spam.append("manga")
    spam.append("papayas")
    spam.append("")
    spam.append("citrus")
    spam.append(" ")
    spam.append("berries")
    spam.append("melons")
    spam.append("")
    spam.append(" ")
    spam.append(20)
    fruits = list_value(spam)

    print(fruits)
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers that have already been provided.